# Database Tables not created

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have just updated phpMyAdmin to the latest version, I use MAMP to design wordpress websites. I have a few current sites which are still working fine but when creating a new database there doesn't seem to be any tables created with it. Not sure what I have done and the following message comes up - Error establishing a database connection. Please help! Not sure what to do!

Comment: Have you verified that the database is running? have you verified whether or not the credentials you're attempting to use are correct. Does the database you attempt to connect to exist? Unless you have a more specific error than `Error establishing a database connection` I doubt we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I followed the instructions for this website when updating phpmyadmin http://blog-en.mamp.info/2013/08/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-mamp-mamp.html I am sure I have followed each step correctly. When I create a database it seems to be working but when I go into it there are no table or no information.  Not sure if this is more helpful for you to help me? Thanks again!